# Unauthorized exception while generating access token using client_Id and client_secret for sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am using a c# code to generate access token for my sharepoint site, using client ID and Client Secret.When I am writing the response using HttpWebResponse I am getting 401:Unauthorized.

I have already generated access token using this code and it worked fine. Now I am getting exception in

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

```
CommonUtility.stGetAccessTokenUrl = string.Format(CommonUtility.stGetAccessTokenUrl, CommonUtility.tenantID);
                myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(CommonUtility.stGetAccessTokenUrl);
                myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                myWebRequest.Method = "POST";

                // Add the below body attributes to the request
                /*
                 *  grant_type  client_credentials  client_credentials
                 client_id  ClientID@TenantID 
                 client_secret  ClientSecret 
                 resource  resource/SiteDomain@TenantID  resourceid/abc.sharepoint.com@tenantID
                 */
                var postData = "grant_type=client_credentials";
                postData += "&client_id=" + CommonUtility.stClientID + "@" + CommonUtility.tenantID;
                postData += "&client_secret=" + (CommonUtility.stClientSecret);
                postData += "&resource=" + CommonUtility.resourceID + "/" + CommonUtility.stSiteDomain + "@" + CommonUtility.tenantID;
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

                using (var stream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();

                var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                string[] stArrResponse = responseString.Split(',');

                //get the access token and expiry time ,etc

                foreach (var stValues in stArrResponse)
                {

                    if (stValues.StartsWith("\"access_token\":"))
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(" Result => " + stValues);
                        accessToken = stValues.Substring(16);
                        //Console.WriteLine(" Result => " + accessToken);
                        accessToken = accessToken.Substring(0, accessToken.Length - 2);
                        // Console.WriteLine(" Result => " + accessToken);
                    }
                }
```

I have changed client Id and client secret only and it started to give me unauthorized exception. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: If it was working earlier and now its not working, the most probable cause would be that your `ClientID` or `ClientSecret` values are not correct and therefore you get `401` unauthorized exception.

Comment: Yeah i have checked it's cause of client Id and client secret, but same I am passing in POSTMAN, and I'm getting access token.

Comment: You would need to check you code on how you are setting up your values for Client Id and ClientSecret. If it is coming up correctly in postman, then you are somewhere assigning your values incorrectly.

Comment: I am generating client Id and client secret using appregnew.aspx in sharepoint. Its working correctly for other client Id and client secret.